# How can I use SignalR in the class library, using the same instance as the webApplication project?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalrcore

I am writing a core class library for SignalR. I created a class library and I added a SignalR package to that. as you know instances are different how can I use webApplication(Asp.Net-Code) project SignalR instance?
Please share with me if you have a sample code
thanks a lot

Comment: Do you want to use the SignalR instance in the core class library you wrote? Does your library have some conditions and configurations for Asp.Net Core to use the SingalR instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I added a singleton class

```
internal class HubClientsConnectedInfo
{
    private IHubCallerClients _clients;
    private IGroupManager _groups;

    public void Set(IHubCallerClients clients, IGroupManager groups)
    {
        _clients ??= clients;
        _groups ??= groups;
    }
    public IHubCallerClients Clients => _clients;
    public IGroupManager Groups => _groups;
}
```

then i register it in `Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HubClientsConnectedInfo>();
```

then i fill it on `BaseHub.OnConnectedAsync`